# Deselect row and remove tick on Xamarin UITableView?

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin

I have overridden the following method which puts a little tick on the cell that has been selected, however the tick stays there and does not get removed when I select a different row.

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    SelectedRow = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

    var cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);

    cell.Accessory = (indexPath.Row >= 0) ? UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark : UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
}
```

How do I make it so that when I select a different cell, the first cell that was selected loses it's tick, so that only one cell at a time has a tick?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I forgot there is a `RowDeslected` method...**

You should be able to use the `RowDeselected` method to accomplish what you want here.

```
public override void RowDeselected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath){
    var deselectedCell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);
    deselectedCell.Accessory = UITableViewAccessory.None;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to set the property `AllowsMultipleSelection` to `false`

```
TableView.AllowsMultipleSelection = false
```